# mysql view difficulty

Tags: mysql, view, syntax

I have a view "vui_trading_period_rates". Selecting * from this view produces

```
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| trading_period_month | ccy_pair_id | price    |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| 201211               | EUR/USD     | 1.294000 |
| 201211               | GBP/USD     | 1.613100 |
| 201210               | EUR/USD     | 1.286700 |
| 201210               | GBP/USD     | 1.614500 |
| 201209               | EUR/USD     | 1.257100 |
| 201209               | GBP/USD     | 1.585700 |
| 201208               | EUR/USD     | 1.231700 |
| 201208               | GBP/USD     | 1.567900 |
| 201207               | EUR/USD     | 1.263500 |
| 201207               | GBP/USD     | 1.565800 |
| 201206               | EUR/USD     | 1.234900 |
| 201206               | GBP/USD     | 1.535100 |
| 201205               | EUR/USD     | 1.326500 |
| 201205               | GBP/USD     | 1.621600 |
| 201204               | EUR/USD     | 1.336300 |
| 201204               | GBP/USD     | 1.602700 |
| 201203               | EUR/USD     | 1.331600 |
| 201203               | GBP/USD     | 1.591400 |
| 201202               | EUR/USD     | 1.304900 |
| 201202               | GBP/USD     | 1.572600 |
| 201201               | EUR/USD     | 1.293900 |
| 201201               | GBP/USD     | 1.549500 |
```

I am trying to create another view from this called "vui_trading_ccy_fluctuations"

This view will contain three columns (trading_period_month, ccy_pair_id, ccy_fluctuation)

An example of how I wish a row to appear is

```
+----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| trading_period_month | ccy_pair_id | ccy_fluctuation |
+----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 201210               | EUR/USD     |  0.005673       |
| 201210               | GBP/USD     | -0.000867       |
```

where ccy_fluctuation for trading_period_monthX (tpx) = [price for (tpX+1) - price for (tpX)]/ price (tpX)

I am stuck on the view this is what I have to far

```
-- --------------------
-- form "Trading Period CCY Fluctuations"
-- --------------------
drop view if exists vui_trading_ccy_fluctuations;
create view vui_trading_ccy_fluctuations as
  select tp.trading_period_month,
         tp.ccy_pair_id,
         format( tp.price, 6) as ccy_fluctuation
  from   vui_trading_period_rates tp
  where  tp.price =
```